# Facebook fql query provides just 100 latest status of a user

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, koala

```
@graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new($access_token)
```

The query below just return latest 100 statuses of certain user instead of all statuses

```
@graph.fql_query("SELECT status_id, message FROM status WHERE uid='user_id'")
```

What is happening? Anyone can guide me if I'm doing something wrong.

Awaiting

Answer (score 1):

Facebook is pretty stingy with the data it returns, unless you ask for more.

Try adding `LIMIT 200` to the end of your query and see if that gives you more. I don't think any table will ever return more than 5000 rows, some tables return far fewer.

If that doesn't work, you may need to make multiple queries, with `LIMIT 100 OFFSET _n_`, where `_n_` would be 101, 201, 301, etc. for a `LIMIT` of 100.

Comment: Limit does not work, anyhow Offest worked but will you tell me how to make multiple queries? do you asking me to loop it? or something else? I want to get all statuses made by certain user and need optimized query. Thanks

Comment: Either make multiple API calls or create an FQL multiquery.

Comment: I up-voted your answer as you showed me the path to do and there is need of some effort to get it done. Thanks @cpilko